# Split a string using strsplit and make a new vector of one part of the split

Tags: r, split, strsplit

I have a matrix, whose column names are all "BT549-[number]", so BT549-0, BT549-1, etc. I'm trying to remove the BT549- prefix and keep only the number. So far, splitting the names on the hyphen works fine, but removing the character string has proven more difficult. For instance, if the matrix is named dset,

```
a <- strsplit(colnames(dset), "-")
b <- unlist(a)

head(b)
[1] "BT549" "0"     "BT549" "10"    "BT549" "11"
```

I've tried splitting the string and keeping the second index of each string using a for loop:

```
a <- for(i in colnames(dset)) {
       unlist(strsplit(colnames(dset[i]), split='-', fixed=TRUE))[2]
     }
# Error in strsplit(colnames(dset[i]), split = "-", fixed = TRUE) : 
#   non-character argument
```

But I don't understand this error. I suspect that there is a simple way to do this, that I am just not thinking of. Any and all advice is quite appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only aim is to delete "BT549-", my solution should work, and does not exploit `strsplit`, but, more easily, `stringr::str_replace_all`.

```
library(stringr)

colnames(dset) <- str_replace_all(colnames(dset), "BT549-", "")
```

Comment: Super simple, as I suspected. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign the results of a `for` to a variable like that. You could just extract every second element of `b`:

```
colnames(dset)<-b[c(FALSE,TRUE)]
```

You could also just extract the second element of every element of `a`:

```
colnames(dset)<-sapply(a,function(x) a[2])
```

Or, more concisely:

```
colnames(dset)<-sapply(a,`[`,2)
```

You could even use `sub` in `base`:

```
colnames(dset)<-sub('^BT549-','',colnames(dset))
```

Comment: in your third example: Why do you use backticks ` ` instead of quotation marks ' ' ? Both do work as I know now.

Comment: @andrasz Both work. `sapply` will accept a character string naming a function, or the function itself as its second argument. ``[`` evaluates to a function, whereas "[" evaluates to a character.